# htaccess redirect from any subdomain to another domain and from directory to query URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im trying to use htaccess to redirect any subdomain and the root of one domain to another domain.
example

anysub.mysite.com or mysite.com redirects to www.anotheriste.com

and also  mysite.com/stuffhere to www.anothersite.com/feed?v=stuffhere

So anything that is not a subdirectory gets redirected to the other domain and anything that is a subdirectory gets redirected to the URL with the query string. Can't seem to get it. One rewrite rules overwrites the other.

Edit:
This is what I got to work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.site.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*\/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting these rules in your .htacccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles http redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

R=301 will redirect with https status 301

L will make last rule

NE is for no escaping query string

QSA will append your existing query parameters

$1 is your REQUEST_URI

Comment: He thanks for the answer, but it doesn't quite work as expected. Reason is, I neglected to mention that the directories are not real. so mysite.com/stuffhere is not an actual directory. Part of what I am doing is short URL's so those directories don't actually exist. After doing a lot of searching I figured out how to accomplish what I needed. I have edited my post to show what I got to work. I believe yours will work fine if they are truly directories. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes that's correct my answer was based on the presence of actual directories. Really glad that you made it into a working solution.